# Android ListFragment, Adapter, ImageView, AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, adapter

I Created a fragmentlist that has rows, each row has a picture, name and phonenumber. made everything regarding the adapter and the list loader... i successfully loaded the list first with default images, then after loading and displaying it to screen i want to load the contact image from the web, so i created a class extending asynctask and while creating each row i executed this class. the thing is that lets say we have a phone number "1234" and i want the row that has this number to have a specific photo, i scroll down fast the list, the photo of many rows changes. Any help?
here is my code:

Adapter class:

```
package Adapters;


import java.util.List;

import com.inneed.R;

import Classes.Contacts;
import Classes.LoadImage;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ContactsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contacts> {
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public ContactsAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    public void setData(List<Contacts> data){
        clear();
        if (data!=null) {
            for (Contacts appEntry : data){
                add(appEntry);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View view;
        if (convertView == null){
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contactrow, parent,false);
        }else {
            view = convertView;
        }
        Contacts item = getItem(position);
        TextView Name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CRName);
        Name.setText(item.getName());
        TextView Mobile = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CRNumber);
        Mobile.setText(item.getMobile());
        if (Mobile.getText().equals("1234"))
        {
            Log.i("MobileXXX",item.getMobile());
            new LoadImage(view).execute("http://image10.bizrate-images.com/resize?sq=60&uid=2216744464");
        }
        if (position%2==0)
        {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_background);
        }
        else view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_background2);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Load Image class asynctask:

```
package Classes;

import java.io.InputStream;

import com.inneed.R;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{
        private View view;
      public LoadImage(View view) {
          this.view = view;
      }

      protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
          String urldisplay = urls[0];
          Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
          try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return mIcon11;
      }

      protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
          ImageView Img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
          Img.setImageBitmap(result);
          this.cancel(true);
      }

}
```

ListFragment Class:

```
import java.util.List;
import Adapters.ContactsAdapter;
import Adapters.FavContactsDataListLoader;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import Classes.Contacts;

public class FavContactsTab extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Contacts>>  {
    ContactsAdapter mAdapter;
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(getActivity());
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        setListShown(false);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }
    @Override
    public Loader<List<Contacts>> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new FavContactsDataListLoader(getActivity());
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Contacts>> arg0, List<Contacts> data) {
        mAdapter.setData(data);
        if (!isResumed()) {
            getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
            setListShown(true);
            setListShownNoAnimation(true);
        }
        else {
            setListShown(true);
            setListShownNoAnimation(true);
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Contacts>> arg0) {
        mAdapter.setData(null);

    }
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Insert desired behavior here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android is reusing views in ListViews. It usually only creates n+1 views with n being the number of views visible on the screen. When you scroll, the disappearing view will be reused as the next visible view. At least that's what happens when you use convertView in the getView() method and that's exactly what you are doing.

Now when that happens and your LoadImage AsyncTask is still running it will modify a view that was originally mapped to another position in the view. Even worse you will start a second LoadImage and the two will modify the same view but with different images.

What you need to do is either not use convertView or prevent the LoadImage from modifying the view once it has finished.
One easy way to do this is to use view.setTag(position) on the view. The LoadImage could read and save the position tag in its constructor and before modifying the view check again the view's position. If it has changed, then the view was re-used for a different position and shouldn't be modified.
I'm sure there are plenty of other ways to achieve the same and maybe more clever ones, but that should give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks, I ll try it when I go back home :D